# Error resubscribing to cancelled subscription

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm working on an android app which makes in app subscriptions and if I subscribe to a product, cancel that subscription and then attempt to subscribe to it again I see this error:

> Error retrieving information from server. [DF-CPA-07]

[image: screenshot]

I've taken to creating new test google accounts to workaround the issue, but unfortunately my credit card has been flagged or something and I now always get "Payment Declined" errors. I'm out of credit cards so I'm wondering if there's some other way I can test this.

Comment: Same thing, but my credit card not blocked after adding to new account and start buy things.